# Return Maximum Value from Group for Year Required

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have looked at a number of similar queries on here all afternoon but can't quite get this query right.

I am trying to return the label associated with the maximum value from a group of results for a unique ID, for the Year required. Here is the code + output:

```
select 
    fs_perm_sec_id, YEAR(date) as [Date by Year], label, sales 
from 
    ff_v2.ff_segreg_af
where 
    fs_perm_sec_id = 'SN9W4D-S-US'
    and YEAR(date) = '2013'
```

Sample data:

```
fs_perm_sec_id  Date by Year    label   sales
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    Japan   26592.96196
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    Europe  16445.23016
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    United States   12851.71355
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    Other Countries 10855.52867
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    Asia Pacific    9730.89435
SN9W4D-S-US 2013    China   5609.94288
```

So in this case, I want to return to fs_perm_sec_id, [Date by Year] and Label - (don't need the sales value). Thus, I want to return

```
SN9W4D-S-US | 2013 | Japan ...as my output
```

Bear in mind, the original table has multiple fs_perm_sec_id's and date entries. So, ultimately I want to highlight the label matching the maximum sales value for all unique entries where the year is 2013.

Below is example of all fields in the table:

```
fs_perm_sec_id  date    ff_segment_type ff_segment_num  adjdate currency    label   sales   opinc   assets  capex   dep
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 1   2000-05-25  USD Japan   26729.2963  NULL    8500.71105  NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 2   2000-05-25  USD Europe  16106.8766  NULL    670.5828    NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 3   2000-05-25  USD United States   15390.4823  NULL    1007.4051   NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 4   2000-05-25  USD Other Countries 9865.9442   NULL    204.08355   NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 5   2000-05-25  USD Asia Pacific    8083.4103   NULL    450.279 NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2012-03-31  REG 6   2000-05-25  USD China   6287.7827   NULL    478.5642    NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 1   2000-05-25  USD Japan   26592.96196 NULL    6571.06184  NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 2   2000-05-25  USD Europe  16445.23016 NULL    568.8144    NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 3   2000-05-25  USD United States   12851.71355 NULL    791.17976   NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 4   2000-05-25  USD Other Countries 10855.52867 NULL    196.66976   NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 5   2000-05-25  USD Asia Pacific    9730.89435  NULL    521.11528   NULL    NULL
SN9W4D-S-US 2013-03-31  REG 6   2000-05-25  USD China   5609.94288  NULL    518.05096   NULL    NULL
```

Thanks v.much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s but then you won't get the 2 points :)

Comment: @marc_s - thanks, I couldn't work out how to do just that...will do in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select fs_perm_sec_id, [Date by Year], label
from
(
select 
    fs_perm_sec_id, YEAR(date) as [Date by Year], label, DENSE_RANK ( ) OVER (order by sales desc) as RankNo
from 
    ff_v2.ff_segreg_af
where 
    fs_perm_sec_id = 'SN9W4D-S-US'
and YEAR(date) = '2013'
) r
where RankNo = 1
```

Comment: Thanks - that works for the single id, what if I have multiple fs_perm_sec_id?

Comment: You can modify DENSE_RANK() use partition by clause.

Comment: (select fs_perm_sec_id, YEAR(date) as [Date by Year], label, DENSE_RANK ( ) 
OVER (partition by fs_perm_sec_id order by sales) as RankNo

Answer (score 0):

Final code was:

```
use FDS3
select fs_perm_sec_id, [Date by Year], label
from
(select fs_perm_sec_id, YEAR(date) as [Date by Year], label, DENSE_RANK ( ) 
OVER (partition by fs_perm_sec_id order by sales) as RankNo
from ff_v2.ff_segreg_af where 
fs_perm_sec_id in 
('SN9W4D-S-US',
'HSDCT7-S-US',
'WHQNFK-S-US',
'PRM2JP-S-US',
'R2KQ06-S-US',
'L7GJB9-S-US',
'P47Z0J-S-US')
and YEAR(date) = '2013'
) r
where RankNo = 1
```